# failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'htpp://localhost:8083/

Tags: react-native, realm

I use realm in my project, but when I tried to enable the debugging it shows an error?

```
failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:8083/
```

What could be the problem? Is there any issues with the react native version?

Comment: Can you provide more information please? There's very little to go on from what you've given us! Cheers

Comment: Realm JS 1.13.0 has a fix to conflicting ports as RH 0.49.0 changed the debug port.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I'm also facing similar issue.

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1034#issuecomment-351289099

Answer (score 0):

For those having this problem on a real Android device:

If you're trying to debug React Native, make sure the device connects to the same network with your computer.